# CompositeId and Identity_Insert

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I have a class mapped like the following:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> 
{
  public FooMap()
  { 
    Table("Foo");
    LazyLoad();
    CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.ID, 
                              kp => kp.ColumnName("Id")
                                      .Type(typeof(long)))
                 .KeyProperty(x => x.ValidFrom);
   }
}
```

On the MSSQL side, Id is identity column and the table's PK is composed of `Id` and `ValidFrom`.

Here's the code I use to save:

```
ISession session = SessionService.GetSession();    
new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Foo ON",
                session.Connection as SqlConnection)
                .ExecuteNonQuery();

try
{
    // performs various versioning checks,
    // then saves using transaction.
    // The session is the same as above
    GenericDataService.Save(myFoo);
}
finally
{
    new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Foo OFF",
                    session.Connection as SqlConnection)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Although I set `Identity_Insert` to `ON`, I get the following exception (when keeping `ID` and setting new `ValidFrom`):

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Foo' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

This is the SQL executed:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, Id, ValidFrom) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Can anyone explain why I still get that exception?

Comment: Is the error a database error or an nhibernate error?  Just a guess but I think that the `Set Identity_Insert Foo on` is probably not run as part of the same transaction. Try using SQL Profiler to see what is actually being executed against the database

Comment: Thanks, Nathan - judging by what you say and a look at my code (the part where it says "//saves using transaction"), that could just be the case. I will check and reply here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem has to do with separate transactions like [Nathan Fisher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29467/nathan-fisher) suggested, then NHibernate's `ITransaction.Enlist(IDbCommand)` method should fix it.  Try something like this:

```
using (var trx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    ExecuteInNHTransaction(session, "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Foo ON");
    session.Save(myFoo);
    ExecuteInNHTransaction(session, "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Foo OFF");
    trx.Commit();
}
```

```
private static void ExecuteInNHTransaction(ISession session, string commandText)
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(commandText,
        (SqlConnection) session.Connection);
    session.Transaction.Enlist(command);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Nathan Fisher's Comment brought me to the problem, but comments cannot be marked as answer...enlisting the command was no option, since I was out of the transaction's scope. Thanks anyway!

Comment: But you have access to the NHibernate `session`!  Why is it not an option?  Just replace your call to `GenericDataService.Save` with `session.SaveOrUpdate`.  What is your solution to the problem - what are you doing instead?

Comment: The method `GenericDataService.Save()` contains a lot of versioning logic that includes, under certain circumstances, that entities must be deleted before the entity is persisted, so this cannot be replaced. All that happens in there, happens in a transaction.